# How I can track `ecommerce:addItem` or `ecommerce:addTransaction` by angulartics2?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, angulartics2

I use [angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2) for tracking pageviews.

How I can track `ecommerce:addItem` or `ecommerce:addTransaction` by angulartics2 in angular 5 application? 
Or maybe I can implement it more native?

*p.s. I added `ga('require', 'ecommerce');`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, angulartics2 haven't an implementation of ecommerce tracking.

You can just use the global `ga` function.

For example *(and you can find native examples in [Ecommerce Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce))*:

```
(window as any).ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});
```

and after all needed adds call `ecommerce:send` by

```
(window as any).ga('ecommerce:send');
```